# $Y-\Delta$ transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I'm working on electrical circuits and the $Y-\Delta$ transformation. Since I thought it was tough for me, I wanted to challenge myself with more problems, and I found this one on the web. However, I can't really see any obvious $T$'s or $\pi$'s for which I can use this transformation. Maybe there's some clever equivalent circuit for which these $T$'s and $\pi$'s become more obvious. If someone can hint me with such a circuit, without presenting the full solution since I want to try by myself, I'd be glad.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the 2 sets of 3 resistors, that are in parallel configuration, to get two equivalent resistors with resistance $10/3 \, \Omega$ and $20/3 \, \Omega$. In this way, you have an equivalent circuit with 4 resistors in series.